# SAS not able to merge two data sets by matching character variables

Tags: character-encoding, sas

I have two data sets, one imported from .xlsx and one from .csv. I did scan, trim, upcase and all those stuffs to clean up the two data sets. I tried both proc sql and data step to merge the two by a character variable. SAS won't be able to find any match. However, when I export the two data set back to .xlsx and then copy and paste the character column from the two sets side by side. Clearly there are many matches, and Excel also recognizes them being the same (use if statement to check them).

What is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely invisible characters of some kind, put a few of your matching values to the log using a hex format to see if they differ.  Or your code is incorrect - since we can't see it, we can only guess. In these cases you need to be able to post sample data - outputting the results from the put statement with a hex format is a good start at least. Right now we don't have much to go on.

Comment: You are right on @Reeza! The hex format shows that they are different. For instance one being 4269726D696E6768616D2020202020 and another being 204269726D696E6768616D20202020, but both shows "Birmingham"...Okay, I check the ascii code table, 20 corresponds to space. But I have used trim()... Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a leading space in the value. Have you tried the COMPRESS() function? Look at the modifiers and pick the one that removes non-printable characters, can't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks @Reeza! Compress() works!

Comment: `strip(compress(string,,'kw'))` will keep only printable characters, then remove any leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have invisible characters in your variables causing the issue. To see these, output the variables with a hex format to see the difference.

You can use the COMPRESS() function to strip any invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to debug the presence of leading spaces in a variable's values.  The default effect of the PUT statement is to remove them.  You need to use $CHAR. or $VARYING. format to preserve the leading spaces.  The $QUOTE. format can also help. Or you could surround the string with printable characters so that PUT doesn't remove the leading spaces by using QUOTE() or CAT() function.

Use the `LEFT()` function to remove the leading spaces.

You could also use the `STRIP()` function to remove both leading and trailing spaces, but SAS comparisons don't care about trailing spaces.  And when you assign the value back into a character variable the trailing spaces will just come back again because SAS character variables are fixed length and padded on the right with spaces.